# How do I find the largest float in a list array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I'm trying to create a python script for the Huntington-Hill apportionment method. For this, I need the population of each state, the number of seats currently assigned to each state, and value **a**, where a = p/sqrt(s*(s+1)). I need to identify which state has the largest **a** value, add one seat to that state and repeat until the state with the smallest population as the largest **a**. I've created row[3] in my list to store **a** values but I'm unable to have python identify the largest one.

I've tried to sort row[3] or simply find the max value, but am told 'float' object is not iterable. If I convert it to a string and then sort, it sorts each digit, giving me a list of 9s and then 8s etc.

```
import math
file_csv = open("statepop2.csv")
data_csv = csv.reader(file_csv)
list_csv = list(data_csv)
for row in list_csv:
    row.append(0)
    row[3] = int(row[1])/math.sqrt(int(row[2])*(int(row[2])+1))
    print(sorted(row[3]))
```

I'm very new to all this, so any help is much appreciated

Edit: It seems this is a problem with the CSV, not with the sort. I'm not sure what's wrong, nor how to upload my CSV file.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code fails to run, because you're reading your values instead of simply coding them into the example.

Comment: row[3] is just a float i.e. from `row[3] = int(row[1])/math.sqrt(int(row[2])*(int(row[2])+1))`.

Comment: But what is `row`? I.e. what does `list_csv` contain?

Comment: list_csv is from a tutorial i got [here](https://www.csestack.org/how-to-read-csv-file-in-python/). The CSV file in question is formatted as ```statename,population,defaultseatnumber``` and then repeats on the next line for all states. For example, ```Alabama,4921532,3```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to sort the value of **a** itself, hence giving a float **as argument** to the sorted() function. It is the same of typing:

`sorted(4.3)`

As 4.3 is not a list but a float, it is **not iterable**.

I suggest to simply create a list and appending the value to that list, then printing the sorted list.

```
import math, csv
file_csv = open("statepop2.csv")
data_csv = csv.reader(file_csv)
list_csv = list(data_csv)
rows = []

for row in list_csv:
    row.append(0)
    row[3] = int(row[1])/math.sqrt(int(row[2])*(int(row[2])+1))
    rows.append(row[3])

print(sorted(rows))
```

If you need some other data from your CSV (i.e. the country name?) to be displayed along with the a value, just makes rows a **dict**:

```
rows = {}
```

Then you can add a dict entry, having the other piece of info as **key**:

```
countryName = row[x]
rows[countryName] = row[3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I amended your suggestion slightly to ```print(max(rows))```, as sorted rows sorted them alphanumerically, rather than in order of magnitude, but it works great now!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `row[3]` is an integer, not a list. You cannot sort an integer.

I am not sure what you exactly want to do, but try this:

```
for row in list_csv:
  row.append(0)
  row[3] = int(row[1])/math.sqrt(int(row[2])*(int(row[2])+1))
print(max([row[3] for row in list_csv]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `max()`.

```
a = [1.2, 3.8, 4.9]
b = max(a)

print(b)
# 4.9
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I'd already tried that, but I've not done a good job at keeping track of what's failed. I tried it anyway to no avail: 'float' object is not iterable. I think this might be a problem with importing from the CSV

Comment: Seems like you are passing a single `float` variable to `max()`. Did you pass e.g. `row` or `row[i]`?